# geom_bar removed 3 rows with missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to create a histogram using `ggplot2` in `R`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_male$explicit_truncated <- trunc(dat_male$explicit_mean)
means2 <- aggregate(dat_male$IAT_D, by=list(dat_male$explicit_truncated,dat_male$id), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
colnames(means2) <- c("explicit", "id", "IAT_D")
sd2 <- aggregate(dat_male$IAT_D, by=list(dat_male$explicit_truncated,dat_male$id), sd, na.rm=TRUE)
length2 <- aggregate(dat_male$IAT_D, by=list(dat_male$explicit_truncated,dat_male$id), length)
se2 <- sd2$x / sqrt(length$x)
means2$lo <- means2$IAT_D - 1.6*se2
means2$hi <- means2$IAT_D + 1.6*se2

ggplot(data = means2, aes(x = factor(explicit), y = IAT_D, fill = factor(id))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lo,ymax=hi, width=.2), position=position_dodge(0.9), data=means2) +
  xlab("Explicit attitude score") + 
  ylab("D-score")
```

For some reason I get the following warning message:
`Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)`. 
And I get the following histogram:
[image]

I really have no clue what is going on.

Please let me know if you need to see anything else of my code, I'm never really sure what to include.

dat_male is a dataset that looks like this (I have only included the variables that I mentioned in this question, as the dataset contains 68 variables):

```
      id explicit_mean     IAT_D         explicit_truncated
5     1        3.1250  0.366158652                  3
6     1        3.3125  0.373590066                  3
9     1        3.6250  0.208096230                  3
11    1        3.1250  0.661983618                  3
15    1        2.3125  0.348246184                  2
19    1        3.7500  0.562406383                  3
28    1        2.5625 -0.292888526                  2
35    1        4.3750  0.560039531                  4
36    1        3.8125 -0.117455439                  3
37    1        3.1250  0.074375196                  3
46    1        2.5625  0.488265849                  2
47    1        4.2500 -0.131005579                  4
53    1        2.0625  0.193040876                  2
55    1        2.6875  0.875420303                  2
62    1        3.8750  0.579146056                  3
63    1        3.3125  0.666095380                  3
66    1        2.8125  0.115607820                  2
68    1        4.3750  0.259929946                  4
80    1        3.0000  0.502709149                  3
```

means2 is a dataset I have used to calculate means, and that looks like this:

```
   explicit id       IAT_D        lo         hi
1        0  0         NaN        NaN        NaN
2        2  0  0.23501191  0.1091807  0.3608431
3        3  0  0.31478389  0.2311406  0.3984272
4        4  0 -0.24296625 -0.3241166 -0.1618159
5        1  1 -0.04010111         NA         NA
6        2  1  0.21939286  0.1109138  0.3278719
7        3  1  0.29097806  0.1973051  0.3846511
8        4  1  0.22965463  0.1209229  0.3383864
```

Now that I see it front of me, it probably has something to do with the NaN's?

Comment: please include the data.

Comment: What is `explicit` variable?  Could you `dput()` your file? and you get the `Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_bar)` warning b/c you have NAs in your dataset

Comment: @DJV I'm really sorry I don't really know how to `dput()` my file.

Comment: @DJV I figured it out! I edited my post

Comment: Is this data you posted the data frame you're trying to plot, or are you still doing some sort of operations on it before plotting? Unless you need help with cleaning or reshaping the data, it's easiest if we just have the data as you want to plot it

Comment: @marblewhite thank you, but it seems like you didn't `dput()` the all `data.frame`. Please notice that some variables are missing like `explicit` or `lo` and `hi`. To `dput()` an object you need to write in the console `dput(the_name_of_the_object)`, and than just copy the output. btw, when ever, someone throws a function at you/ you don't remember what a function does, use the help `?`. For example, `?dput()` would give you: `Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection, or uses one to recreate the object` :)

Comment: @DJV You are right, I excluded some variables as the dataset is very big and some variables take up a lot of space without really telling you anything. I think I have added all the needed information to the post now. means2 is based on data from the dat_male dataset so that I would have the means of some variables to work with.

Answer (score 1):

From your dataset it seems like everything is alright.

The errors that you get are an indication that your `data.frame` has empty values (i.e. `NaN` and `NA`). 
I actually got two warning messages:
`Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 rows containing missing values
(geom_bar). 
2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values
(geom_errorbar).`

Regarding the plot, because you don't have any zero values under `explicit`, you don't see it in the graph. Similarly, because you have `NA`s under `lo` and `hi` for one in `explicit`, you don't get the corresponding error bar.

Dataset:

```
means2 <- read.table(text = "   explicit id       IAT_D        lo         hi
1        0  0         NaN        NaN        NaN
                     2        2  0  0.23501191  0.1091807  0.3608431
                     3        3  0  0.31478389  0.2311406  0.3984272
                     4        4  0 -0.24296625 -0.3241166 -0.1618159
                     5        1  1 -0.04010111         NA         NA
                     6        2  1  0.21939286  0.1109138  0.3278719
                     7        3  1  0.29097806  0.1973051  0.3846511
                     8        4  1  0.22965463  0.1209229  0.3383864",
                     header = TRUE)
```

plot:

```
means2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(explicit), y = IAT_D, fill = factor(id))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lo,ymax=hi, width=.2),
                position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
  xlab("Explicit attitude score") + 
  ylab("D-score")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I took out the NA's with na.rm=TRUE for both geom_bar and geom_error bar. But isn't it still weird that the most left bar (explicit attitude score 1) takes up the space of both factor(id) 0 and 1?
Also, thank you for being so patient with me haha.

Comment: You're most welcome and glad I could help. It's because  the "zero" group doesn't have any values in 1.